# How to get javascript trace line-by-line in firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

I'm trying to debug a lengthy script, which breaks down some time after the execution started. Debugging it in firebug step-by-step is a nightmare.

FlowTrace does a good job of showing me the function calls, but having line-by-line execution information on the script would be invaliable.

Is there any way I could collect (and store) this information in firebug or by using firefoxes api?

Comment: Not answering your question but when I have a problem like this I use a variety of a binary search algorithm. You put some breakpoints or some console prints at key points "in the middle" of the execution. Then find out if it works before that point or not. If not, subdivide the code before the first point to narrow it down. After a few of these you either find a problem or you get it small enough that a single-step in the debugger is feasible. Then you have one bug. Repeat until all bugs are gone.

Answer (score 0):

this is a stupid solution , but i use alert();
in fire fox , when i have to debug javascript in fire fox .
:D

Answer (score 0):

you can use break points and then trace it step by step with firebug in chrome or firefox... its easy and reduces efforts allot.